# how do we get the apikey of VSTS nuget package management service

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

Just installed the nuget package management service from Visual Studio marketplace. I was unable to find the apikey of the service.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I do not believe there is an api key. You can specify any non-empty string as long as the credentials being used are valid looking at the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/publish).

Comment: How does it do the credentials ?

Comment: If you are on Windows you should be able to use the credential provider that is available to download when as shown in the Connect to Feed screenshot. If you are not on Windows then a better alternative is to create a personal access token and add it to your NuGet.Config file. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/nuget-exe

Comment: The credential can be any username paired with a PAT with packaging permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The NuGet client push command requires an API key, you can use any
>   non-empty string you want.

Related article: [Publish a NuGet package from the command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/publish#publish-nuget-package)

Comment: it is not clear then which way the client authenticates itself?

Comment: That's kind of a pain. I'm owner of the feed and any push answers with error 401. It should provide a way to set the credentials while pushing

Comment: use the --interactive flag